# How can I change term order number to invoice number?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation

In Germany, the tax office sometimes has a problem if the order number appears on an invoice. Instead, it should say invoice number. So this is only about the description.

I realise that I can change the Woocommerce translation file so that the term is displayed differently.

Is there possibly a hook for this?

Comment: Try the `gettext` hook like in [those threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+gettext)